# Set default wireless adapter

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, wireless-networking, network-adapter

I just acquired a Wi-Fire long-range wi-fi adapter, and I would like to test it with my Ubuntu desktop computer. However, my machine defaults to using an internal, discrete wireless card (not hard-wired into the motherboard.) How can I set my new wireless adapter as the default wireless connection? How can I disable my internal wireless card (without opening my computer case)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your external and internal cards are unlikely to use the same kernel driver, so try blacklisting the module.

Do `lspci | grep Network`. This will output a line like

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

In rare cases your wired adapter will be enumerated as a `Network controller` too (instead of `Ethernet controller`), so check the name of the device too. Probably it will contain 'wireless' or such. The XX:YY.Z number on start of line is the PCI slot number, record it for the next command.

Then do `lspci -v -s XX:YY.Z | grep driver`. It will output something like:

```
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

`ath9k` in my case is the name of module that provides connectivity through built-in WiFi adapter. Execute the command `echo "blacklist MODULE" >/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-internal-wifi.conf` in root shell, of course substituting MODULE with the driver name from previous step.

You can start the root shell by launching it in the menu or typing `sudo su`. It has a prompt ending in '#'.

Reboot, and you should have your internal adapter disabled. If you want to revert everything, just delete the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-internal-wifi.conf` file